# Telerik WPF RadImageEditor.Image not databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, telerik

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <telerik:RadImageEditor
        x:Name="ImageEditor"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Image="{Binding RadImage}"
        ScaleFactor="0" />

    <!-- For comparison -->
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Image}" />
</Grid>
```

CSharp

```
private void Show() {
    // download image from url
    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.example.com/image.jpg"));
    RadImage = new RadBitmap(Image);
}

// Properties
public RadBitmap RadImage
{
    get { return _radImage; }
    set { _radImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}

public BitmapSource Image
{
    get { return _image; }
    set { _image = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

I tried to use [RadImageEditor](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radimageeditor/getting-started) WPF control and what to show image by databinding.

The `<Image />` shows downloaded image perfectly but `<telerik:RadImageEditor />` does not.

Doesn't this control support databinding?

Comment: Just a guess, but you could try to make sure that `Image` is already loaded when passed to the RadBitmap constructor, either by setting the BitmapImage's CacheOption to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`, or by using an appropriate `BitmapFrame.Create()` method.

Comment: @Clemens // thanks you help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Clemens gives a hint. Thanks.

I think it could cause by delayed loading so I can resolve this issue as below.

```
private void Show() {
    if (Image != null)
        WeakEventManager<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource, EventArgs>.RemoveHandler(Image, nameof(Image.DownloadCompleted), OnImageOnDownloadCompleted);

    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.example.com/image.jpg"));
    WeakEventManager<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource, EventArgs>.AddHandler(Image, nameof(Image.DownloadCompleted), OnImageOnDownloadCompleted);
}

private void OnImageOnDownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    RadImage = new RadBitmap(Image);
}
```